# XSLT duplicating text nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to figure out how to apply a styling element to different structure elements.

My XML looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <catalog>
        <cd>
            <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
            <artist><bold>Bob</bold> Dylan</artist>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Hide your <bold>heart</bold></title>
            <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        </cd>
    </catalog>
```

And my lastest XSLT attempt looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="bold">
<b><xsl:value-of select="." /></b>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/catalog">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="cd">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title" /><xsl:apply-templates/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist" /><xsl:apply-templates/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the result duplicates the data instead of just having the desired parts in bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need:

```
      <xsl:for-each select="cd">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:apply-templates select="title"/></td>
          <td><xsl:apply-templates select="artist"/></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
```

Since you don't have any templates matching `title` or `artist` the default will be to copy their text nodes to the output. You don't need to do that yourself.

Here's a modification that uses more idiomatic "push" processing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="bold">
    <b><xsl:value-of select="." /></b>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/catalog">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Artist</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="cd"/>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="cd">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:apply-templates select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:apply-templates select="artist"/></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option that uses fewer explicit element matches. In many cases, this will be what you want, because it's simpler and more flexible. In some cases, this *won't* be what you want, because you'll want to handle each element individually. YMMV.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/catalog">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Artist</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="cd">
        <tr><xsl:apply-templates /></tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="cd/*">
        <td><xsl:apply-templates /></td>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="bold">
        <b><xsl:apply-templates /></b>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're processing it once using xsl:value-of and then once again using xsl:apply-templates; if you don't want it processed twice, then just cut one of these out.